# How to Call multiple notebooks concurrently from one notebook in databricks

Tags: azure, scala, multiprocessing, threadpool, databricks

I was trying to call multiple notebook to other notebook concurrently in azure databricks.

I have used dbutils.notebook.run method to call other notebook in scala program.

Based on if condition respective notebooks should be called. I was able to call but they are running one by one not concurrently.

And got to know I can do this using Multiprocessing/Threadpool but i am not sure how to implement.Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

Databricks provides [advanced examples](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#run-multiple-notebooks-concurrently) on how to run notebooks concurrently.
Download the `.dbc` and import it in your workspace.

There is also the [new task orchestration](https://docs.databricks.com/data-engineering/jobs/jobs-quickstart.html) which can help with simple flows.